# Need guidance on LSTM implementation in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I need help implementing a sequence classifier prediction using Keras APIs.

So far, I've managed to get the data in a specific format that I believe should be suited for input into Keras, however, I am still failing to understand the exact specifics on what parameters I need to change.

Here is the situation:

What I have is a number of targets, with each target representing an independent event.

Each target contains multiple detections of varying number. For example, one target might contain 33 detections, while another might contain 54. Each detection is just a single value between 0-1. The original dataset has a shape of `(# samples, # detections)`
I want to be able to input the sequence of these detections into a LSTM to classify the overall target into two classes for ALL targets
So far, I've pre-pended 0s to the detection sequences such that they are equal in length. Now the dataset has a shape of `(# samples, 77(max detections across all targets))`

Then, I create the time steps of an arbitrary window size of 7. The dataset has shape `(# samples, 77-window+1 = 71, 7)`.

In case this isn't quite clear, the sequence has been turned from 1 long

```
[1, 2, 3, ... 77]
```

into 71 sequences of 7 that look like:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
..., 
[71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77]]
```

Now that my data is in the format `(# samples, # windows per sample, window)`, what tweaks should I make in order to obtain the output of 1 classification output per sample?

I've tried looking online at keras's documentation about TimeDistributed layers and LSTM layers, at all of the blog posts on MachineLearningMastery, and other forum posts, but I couldn't quite understand enough for me to figure out how to use the API for my specific case.
Here's what I have so far:

```
train_new.shape
output: (31179, 71, 7)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(71, 7), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_new, label_train, validation_data=(test, label_test), epochs=3, batch_size=128)

Returns: 
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_3 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (31179, 1)
```

Any direction or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This is worded quit confusingly, have you tried not starting with LSTM? You arbitrarily assigning a timestep, so I’m not convinced this is a timeseries problem...

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to take sequence with length (timestamp,windows-size) and get one number(class), or do you want to get number(class) for each timestamp?

Comment: The detections of the target are in order of time, that's why I want to utilize an LSTM. I'm not too sure what timestep I should be using for this problem, so I arbitrarily decided on 7. I want to get one classification per sample, that is, one output value per group of (71, 7) length sequences.